# Javascript Multidimensional Array Issue

Tags: javascript, suitescript

I'm working on a project that only has access to base JS no console/alerts etc based on an ERP scripting system.

I'm using the ERP systems output for a search which is essentially `search[index].getValue(column[index])` all of the values being retrieved from this are correct and verified.

My data comprises of the following columns

sku, displayname, locid, onhand, onorder, committed, backordered, intransit, available, id

The data source i'm using pulls 2 search results in for each SKU, one for each of 2 locations, "13" & "4". my goal is that if the locid of the line is 4 I add to an array (indexed by the sku) with the available fields, if the locid is 13 I then want to add it to the same line but with slightly different field names (prefixed by a q).

code below

```
searchLength = search.length;   
    var items = [];
    for(var i = 0, len = search.length; i < len; i++) {

        var sku = search[i].getValue(columns[0]);
    //  html += search[i].getValue(columns[0]) + " - " + search[i].getValue(columns[1]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[2]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[3]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[4]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[5]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[6]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[7]) + " - " +search[i].getValue(columns[8]) + "<br>";
        items[sku] = [];

            items[sku]['displayname'] = search[i].getValue(columns[1]);
            items[sku]['id'] = search[i].getValue(columns[9]);
            items[sku]['loc'] =  search[i].getValue(columns[2]);


            if(search[i].getValue(columns[2]) == "4") {

                items[sku]['onhand'] = search[i].getValue(columns[3]);
                items[sku]['onorder'] = search[i].getValue(columns[4]);
                items[sku]['committed'] = search[i].getValue(columns[5]);
                items[sku]['backordered'] = search[i].getValue(columns[6]);
                items[sku]['intransit'] = search[i].getValue(columns[7]);
                items[sku]['available'] = search[i].getValue(columns[8]);
            } 
            if(search[i].getValue(columns[2]) == "13") {

                items[sku]['qonhand'] = search[i].getValue(columns[3]);
                items[sku]['qonorder'] = search[i].getValue(columns[4]);
                items[sku]['qcommitted'] = search[i].getValue(columns[5]);
                items[sku]['qbackordered'] = search[i].getValue(columns[6]);
                items[sku]['qintransit'] = search[i].getValue(columns[7]);
                items[sku]['qavailable'] = search[i].getValue(columns[8]);
            } 


}
```

my problem is that no matter how many times i've tried to rewrite this, whenever I output items[sku] that specific array only ever has one set of the values i.e. either available or qavailable is in the array, never both.

I've been tweaking this for hours and I'm sure I'm just missing something small if anyone could assist.

edit below to show sample output where all fields should appear in the array, this was produced by the following function http://locutus.io/php/var/var_dump/

```
array(1) {
    [ABC123456] =>
    array(9) {
            [displayname] =>
            string(39) "Product Display Name Here"
            [id] =>
            string(4) "4745"
            [loc] =>
            string(1) "4"
            [onhand] =>
            string(4) "6816"
            [onorder] =>
            string(0) ""
            [committed] =>
            string(4) "1872"
            [backordered] =>
            string(0) ""
            [intransit] =>
            string(0) ""
            [available] =>
            string(4) "4944"
    }
}
```

further edit to show data going into the function

```
ABC123456, Product Display Name Here, 13, 9552, , , , , ,9552
ABC123456, Product Display Name Here, 4, 6816, ,1872, , , ,4944
```

Comment: Your code is using arrays where it really should be using plain objects (`{}` instead of `[]`). Arrays in JavaScript are for **numbered** properties.

Comment: JS does not have multidimensional arrays, rather it has arrays and objects. And for this script, you should be using objects, which can be assigned using `var items = {};`

Comment: I've converted them over to the above suggestions and still facing the same end result.

Comment: Can you add the output you mention `item[sku]`? The logic of your if statements are exclusive because `search[i].getValue(columns[2])` cannot equal both "4" and "13".

Comment: @dan08 What do you mean by "JS does not have multidimensional arrays"? Of course it does. You can make arrays of array all day long as deeply nested as you want.

Comment: Oh yea, I guess I was thinking associative arrays, because that's what the OP is acutally trying to construct.

Comment: What's `columns`, anyway?

Comment: @dan08 output shown

Comment: @Tomalak they are search column indexes from the ERP, they work completely fine

Comment: @user1372212 Double check your if-conditions.

Comment: That's not my point. You refer to it in your code, you need to show what the variable contains, if nothing else then to show us all data that is relevant to your snippet of code.

Comment: @dan08 Have done, if I put trigger statements in they trigger just fine, updated to show the data going into the IF

Comment: @Tomalak i've put a sample of the data they are feeding through

Comment: It's still unclear how and where `columns` is defined in your JS code. Also, you seem to have a proper associative array with keys *and* values in PHP. I am beginning to suspect you do not transfer the data properly to JS to begin with.

Comment: @Tomalak These are defined using the scripting interface to the ERP i.e. columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn("internalid","inventoryLocation",null);  putting in the 40 or so lines of code that handle my search when I have tested the output at great length would distract from the issue at hand.

Comment: That's true, but outlining it with one or two examples to give proper context would actually help, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally pieced it together from your edits and your comments.

You are trying to populate `$items[sku]` across multiple passes through your loop using the common `sku` key.

However, you reset the `item[sku]` on each iteration with `items[sku] = [];`

So a couple things:

1. `items[sku]` should be an object instead of an array.
2. You should not reset to an empty object if it is set.

So around line 7 in your code snippet, change `items[sku] = [];` to:

```
if( !items.hasOwnProperty(sku) || typeof(items[sku]) != 'object' ){
  items[sku] = {};
}
```

That way you only set to an empty object of already empty.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, had moved the initial declaration into the loop while trying something, that works a treat. can't believe of all the things that was it. Greatly appreciate the help!